# using ruby to extract email body from Microsoft graph rest api outlook message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, actionmailer, mail-gem

I am fetching emails from Outlook through Microsoft Graph or Rest Api directly from Ruby without using any Microsoft SDK.

The problem I am facing is that I can't get the email message body from the response returned by Microsoft. Using the Ruby Mail gem, I have tried to parse the response by doing:

```
 response = HTTParty.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages", headers: headers)

response_body = response.body
parsed_body = JSON.parse(response_body)
returned_email_values = parsed_body.dig('value')
first_email = returned_email_values.first
#I tried mail = Mail.read_from_string(first_email ) and also, mail = Mail.new(first_email )

mail = Mail.read_from_string(first_email )
mail.body.raw_source
```

which returns:

```
 "{\"contentType\"=>\"html\", \"content\"=>\"<html>\\r\\n<head>\\r\\n<meta http-equiv=\\\"Content-Type\\\" content=\\\"text/html; charset=utf-8\\\">\\r\\n<meta content=\\\"text/html; charset=utf-8\\\">\\r\\n</head>\\r\\n<body>\\r\\nLet's go&nbsp;\\r\\n<div><br>\\r\\n</div>\\r\\n<div style=\\\"font-size:100%; color:#000000\\\">\\r\\n<div>-------- Original message --------</div>\\r\\n<div>From: Well &lt; **@outlook.com&gt; </div>\\r\\n<div>Date: 09/01/2018 22:33 (GMT&#43;00:00) </div>\\r\\n<div>To: **@yahoo.com </div>\\r\\n<div>Subject: it is httparty </div>\\r\\n<div><br>\\r\\n</div>\\r\\n</div>\\r\\nhttparty rocks\\r\\n</body>\\r\\n</html>\\r\\n\"}"
```

How do I parse this so I get the email body text, without the html markdown which should return **httparty rocks**.

For reference, here is a link to [Microsoft's documentation for the api](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/message) and this is the full api response that is returned to me:

```
- "@odata.etag": W/"CQAAABYAA***hjCagexQJczqiL***dRAAAxqsAe"
id: ****TAwCgBGAAAD2TG**i9L9AAAgE2n4YwmoHsUCXM6***
createdDateTime: '2018-01-09T23:07:52Z'
lastModifiedDateTime: '2018-01-09T23:07:52Z'
changeKey: **AAADafhjCag**JczqiL0v2dRAAA**
categories: []
receivedDateTime: '2018-01-09T23:07:52Z'
sentDateTime: '2018-01-09T23:08:36Z'
hasAttachments: false
internetMessageId: "<**FT028.enam01.prod.protection.outlook.com>"
subject: 'Re: it is httparty'
bodyPreview: "Let's go\r\n\r\n---- Original message -----\r\nFrom: Well <***@outlook.com>\r\nDate: 09/01/2018 22:33 (GMT+00:00)\r\nTo: ***@yahoo.com\r\nSubject: it is httparty\r\n\r\nhttparty rocks"
importance: normal
parentFolderId: **1LTgyOTYtMDACLTAwCA**0aVdJhhKHRI1AEA2**
conversationId: **NiZmYAZC0wYTc**gyOtMDACLTAwCg**
isDeliveryReceiptRequested: 
isReadReceiptRequested: false
isRead: false
isDraft: false
webLink: https://outlook.live.com/owa/?ItemID=****1AcA2n4Yw**%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem
inferenceClassification: focused
body:
  contentType: html
  content: "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;
  charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\nLet's
  go&nbsp;\r\n<div><br>\r\n</div>\r\n<div style=\"font-size:100%; color:#000000\">\r\n<div>--------
  Original message --------</div>\r\n<div>From: Well &lt; **@outlook.com&gt;
  </div>\r\n<div>Date: 09/01/2018 22:33 (GMT&#43;00:00) </div>\r\n<div>To: ***@yahoo.com
  </div>\r\n<div>Subject: it is httparty </div>\r\n<div><br>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\nhttparty
  rocks\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
sender:
   emailAddress:
     name: well
     address: ***@yahoo.com
from:
  emailAddress:
    name: well
    address:***@yahoo.com
toRecipients:
  - emailAddress:
     name: bee
     address: **@outlook.com
ccRecipients: []
bccRecipients: []
replyTo: []
```

Comment: you mean you want to get email body text, without html markdown?

Comment: @nattfodd yes. The email body text without the html markdown should return ** httparty rocks**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to ask the server to return the plain-text version of the body. From [the docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_messages#request-headers):

`Prefer: outlook.body-content-type`: The format of the `body` and `uniqueBody` properties to be returned in. Values can be "text" or "html". If the header is not specified, the `body` and `uniqueBody` properties are returned in HTML format. Optional.

Here's how I specified the header in Postman:

[image]